# C# Adding values to pictureboxes

Tags: c#, if-statement, picturebox

I just recently posted something earlier regarding a C# game project I am working on in Microsoft visual C# express and after trial and error the code that I have presented underneath will not work. Does anyone have any advice or help they could give me on how to get it to work? the part of the code with the brackets and asterisks and arrows is the error that will not work for me. (NOTE: I am making a Form on Microsoft Visual C# express.)

```
if (buttonFlag[0])
{
    return;
}

if (accept)
{
    return;
}


textBox2.Text = "";
textBox1.Text = "";
offerCounter++;

---> [[[ **pictureBox2.Image**]]]<--- = tempLabel = buttonList[0].ToString();
LostValues(tempLabel);
textBox1.Text = "-> you just opend " + tempLabel + "\n";

CallZero(tempLabel);

if (offerCounter == 20)
{
    finalValue = GetFinalValue();
    MessageBox.Show("You win " + finalValue.ToString());

    textBox1.Text = "Game is over" + "\n";
    textBox1.Text += "you won: " + finalValue.ToString();
    label16.Content = "you won:";
    label17.Content = finalValue.ToString();
    label18.Text = "Game Over";
    accept = true;
}

if (offerCounter <= 18)
{
    if ((offerCounter % 3) == 0)
    {
        GenerateNewOffer();
        textBox1.Text += "-> you have a new offer ";
        MessageBox.Show("you recieved a new offer !");
        textBox2.Text = newOffer.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        offerRemainder = 3 - (offerCounter % 3);
        textBox1.Text += "-> Open " + offerRemainder.ToString() + "more box(es) for new offer";
    }
}
else
{
    textBox2.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: Can you explain bit more about what you are trying to do?

Comment: You'll probably need to do much better than simply dumping a big section of code and saying it doesn't work. Learn to think like a programmer. What doesn't work? What does it do? What were the error messages? What have you tried? That said, if you are trying to assign a string to an `Image`, then yes that would definitely not work because an image is not a string.

Comment: And can you explain a bit more about what the code is doing, instead of working?

Comment: i am making trying to make the picturebox have a value and to be honest im new to this so i am experimenting and have not a sure clue to what i accomplished but my goal is to give the picture box a value.
@SivaCharan

Comment: the code was supposed to be giving the picturebox a value @phoog

Comment: i am quite sorry im not able to post enough info to allow people to help me i just start coding and i just joined the site i will try to edit it and make it clearer @JonathanWood

Comment: @Adam, ok, so what does the code do instead of giving the picturebox a value?

Comment: @Adam How do you expect to assign a string to an Image? If you simply want to display a string, use a Label. And look at Jonathan's comment.

Comment: What does the title of the question have to do with the question?

Comment: @phoog the code was -i think- supposed to generate a random number when the picturebox is clicked.

Comment: @EricLippert i fixed the title

Comment: @Adam if you're *not even sure what the code is supposed to do* then how can you know whether it is correct?  Start with *requirements* -- a statement of the problem you're trying to solve.  Then devise a test to determine whether a program meets the requirements (solves the problem).  Then start writing the program, and keep at it until the test passes.  Requirements and tests need not be formal; the requirement might be the statement *I want a program to print "Hello, World!" to the console.* The simplest test for that is to run the program and observe its output.

Comment: @phoog i guess theres nothing much you guys can help with being as it is my fault for my lack of explanatory skills,  i guess its back to the drawing board thanks for helping!.

Comment: @Adam good luck. One of my tasks at work is to provide support to users of one of the products I maintain. Perhaps only 10% of support requests have a clear statement of the problem.  With the others, I have to ask: "Tell me what *should* happen, and tell me what *is* happening."  ... Do come back when you have a clearer understanding of the problem, although, if you're anything like me, the process of formulating the question will lead you to the solution.

Answer (score 2):

[The PictureBox.Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.image.aspx) Property takes an [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) instance.  Read MSDN for both and code accordingly.